# Canon imageclass MF4420w printer cant work with mac osx 10.8

Tags: macbook-pro, printing, error, driver, canon

There seems to be no legit drivers available for the Canon MF4420w imageclass printers which dont seem to work.

Comment: And you did your homework and could not find it at Canon!

Answer (score 2):

That happens with Canon but also with HP printers as far i know

Your printer is not from this world! :)

What I mean by that it is not supported on USA sites.

But the good news is it is supported on Asian sites.

So go here and get your driver.

[image]

http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/P/search?model=imageCLASS+MF4420w&menu=download&filter=0&tagname=g_os